# PhP - how to catch fatal errors in a static class

Tags: php, json

I have a static class and I want to be able to treat fatal error. I'm pasting the method below so you understand better what I mean:

```
public static function getInformationDataArrayWithJsonInput($formConfigType, $application_data_json){

    set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
    register_shutdown_function('fatalErrorShutdownHandler');

    $ret = [];
    $formConfigs = FormConfig::find(array('form_config_type_id='.$formConfigType, 'order" => "ordination ASC'));

    if($formConfigs->count() == 0)
        return $ret;

    $json = $application_data_json;
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    $jsonObj = json_decode($json);

    foreach ($formConfigs as $field){
        $str = "if(\$jsonObj->".$field->json_property."){";
        $str .= "\$ret['".$field->label."'] = \$jsonObj->".$field->json_property.";";
        $str .= "} else {";
        $str .= "\$ret['".$field->label."']=null;";
        $str.="}";

        try{
            eval($str);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());

        }
    }

    return $ret;

}

   function fatalErrorShutdownHandler()
{

    die('fatalErrorShutdownHandler');

    $last_error = error_get_last();
    if ($last_error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
        // fatal error
        myErrorHandler(E_ERROR, $last_error['message'], $last_error['file'], $last_error['line']);
    }
}

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{

    die('myErrorHandler');

    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so let it fall
        // through to the standard PHP error handler
        return false;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
            echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
            echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
            exit(1);
            break;

        case E_USER_WARNING:
            echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;

        default:
            echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
            break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}
```

This method receives a `json` and a string with the property of which I want to retrieve the value from. myErrorHandler and fatalErrorShutDownHandler are implemented according to [this article](https://insomanic.me.uk/php-trick-catching-fatal-errors-e-error-with-a-custom-error-handler-cea2262697a2#.mla1uerwz)

Let's say I passed `products[1].limits[0].value` as the json property and there is no `products[1]` this will cause a fatal error so I would have to return null. That's my problem, I can't go into the catch to do the proper treatment.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `eval` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/277224/1255289)

Comment: @miken32 I saw this answer, and applied register_shutdown_function and it's never reached

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be using `eval` here, and should avoid its use whenever possible. Variable property names are easy enough to do, and by using intermediate variables you make it easier to read. Then a simple [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) does the work for you.

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($json);

foreach ($formConfigs as $field) {
    $prop = $field->json_property;
    $label = $field->label;
    $ret[$label] = property_exists($jsonObj, $prop) ? $jsonObj->$prop : null;
}
```